# select multiple buttons on selecting two buttons (buttons in between the two buttons have to be selected)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Lets say we have the fallowing code:

```html
Selected Seats
<input type="button" class="seat selected" value="a1">
<input type="button" class="seat selected" value="b2">
<input type="button" class="seat selected" value="c3">
<input type="button" class="seat" value="d4">
<input type="button" class="seat" value="e5">
<input type="button" class="seat" value="f6">
```

visit http://jsfiddle.net/victornpb/7j8vj/
on selecting a1 and f6 in the above case all a1,b2,c3,d4,e5,f6 have be selected automatically

Comment: I don't see what's not working here? Maybe I'm temporarily blind.

Comment: @Gustaf He wants that if you first select seat a1 and after that f6 all seats between are also selected.

Comment: Ah! I though he said that that was happening and that it was the problem. Thanks for polishing my glasses @Mivaweb

Comment: thanks @gustaf 
is there any possibility ?

Comment: why  you have multiple selected options in class?

Comment: i believe you should use an array to hold the buttons so you should iterate until you can reach the second selected index

Comment: @user1887128 View my update answer with a working solution

Answer (score 2):

I've made some changes to your code...
I think this can be a good beginning.

I added this function :

```
function selectAll(seats) {
seats.forEach(function(seat) {
    seat.className = seat.className + ' selected';
});
}
```

It sets the selected class to all the elements in the array

And I changed your seatClick function to this one :

```
function seatClick(seat) {
seat = (this instanceof HTMLInputElement ) ? this : seat;
var firstSelected;
var selectedSeats = [];
var thisInputHasAlreadyBeenSeen = false;
var confirmedSeats = [];
if (seat.classList.contains('reserved')==false) {

    if (seat.classList.toggle('selected')) {
        addSeat(document.getElementById('seats'), seat.value);
        $(".seat").each(function() {
            if(this != seat) {
            if(firstSelected == null && this.classList.contains('selected')) {
                firstSelected = this;
                selectedSeats.push(firstSelected);
                confirmedSeats = selectedSeats.slice();
            } else if (firstSelected) {
                if(this.classList.contains('selected')) {
                    selectedSeats.push(this);
                confirmedSeats = selectedSeats.slice();
                   }
                if(!this.classList.contains('reserved')) {
                selectedSeats.push(this);
                 }
            else{
                if(!thisInputHasAlreadyBeenSeen) {
                selectedSeats = [];
                firstSelected = null;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            }
            } else {
                selectedSeats.push(this);
                confirmedSeats = selectedSeats.slice();
                if(firstSelected == null) {
                    thisInputHasAlreadyBeenSeen = true;
                    firstSelected = this;
                }
            }
        });
        if(confirmedSeats.length > 1) {
        selectAll(confirmedSeats);
        }
    } else {
        removeSeat(document.getElementById('seats'), seat.value);
    }

} else {
    alert("This seat is reserved!\nPlease select another seat");
    removeSeat(document.getElementById('seats'), seat.value);
    return;
}
}
```

Basically what it does:

There are two arrays : one for temporary seats (**temporary array**) (some may be not selected in some cases), and one for the seats that will be selected (**actual array**)

It loops through all your seats.

If it encounters a blank seat, it puts it inside a temporary array, if the actual array has already been started.

If it encounters a "selected" seat, it either start the actual array or confirm the temporary array data by copying it inside the actual array.

If it encounters a reserved seat, it stops looping...

jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/7J8vj/94/

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution should be using the jQuery functions `nextUntil()` and `add()`:

```
var $first;
var $last;
var loop = false;

$('input.seat').click(function() {

    // Reset the seats if you select a new seat after a range was already defined
    if($first !== undefined  && $last !== undefined) {
        $first = undefined;
        $last = undefined;
        $('.seat').removeClass('selected');
        loop = false;
    }

    // Set first seat
    if($first === undefined) {
        $first = $(this);
        $first.addClass('selected');
    } else {
        // Set last seat
        if($last === undefined) {
            $last = $(this);
            loop = true;
        }
    }

    // Loop over all seats between first and last
    if(loop) {
        $('.seat').removeClass('selected');
        if(!$(this).hasClass('reserved'))
            $first.nextUntil($last,':not(.reserved)').andSelf().add($last).addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

What this code does is take the first selected seat, after that take all other elements until the last-seat. But the last seat also needs to be added to your list so you need to add this last seat using the `add()` function.

You still need to do some checkup, like for example if one seat is already reserved in this range, you have to exclude it.

Short example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VDesign/cfq2xpmh/2/)

Comment: Your fiddle doesnt exist anymore

Answer (score 0):

You should apply rowid to the seats row, so when user clicks on any two seats, and if both matches then it should select all seats in between them

Comment: can you provide us with any example ?

Comment: Okey trying logic on fiddle

Comment: Is it possible to use jquery here?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. You get the clicked `index`, loop through the seats and if the clicked `index` is larger than the current `index` you run the `addSeat()` function. I added jQuery to make life easier.

```
var clickedIndex = $( ".seat" ).index( this );
$('.seat').each(function(index){
     if(!$(this).hasClass('selected') && clickedIndex > index){
         addSeat($('#seats'), $(this).val());
     }             
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made kind of prototype. Logics can be made around it.

I have used nextUntil as some of the above answers.

Added a div with class `.row`

```
 $(".row").find('.a1.selected').nextUntil(".selected").css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});
```

**[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/7J8vj/17/)**

Answer (score 0):

i ve made a pure js solution that works for me.

add these 3 functions:

```
function mapSeats(){
    return document.getElementsByClassName("seat");
}

function findIndex(object,value){
    for(i=0;i<object.length;i++){
        if(object[i].value==value)
            return i;
    }
    return null;
}

function isSelected(element){
    if ( (" " + element.className + " ").replace(/[\n\t]/g, " ").indexOf(" selected ") > -1 )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

and this is is the seatClick:

```
var start= end = -1;

//called everytime a seat is clicked
function seatClick() {

    if (this.classList.contains('reserved')==false) {


        if(start == -1)
            start = this.value;
        else if(end == -1)
            end = this.value;

        if(start != -1 && end != -1){

            seats = mapSeats();

            console.log(seats);

            indexS =  findIndex(seats,start);
            indexE = findIndex(seats,end);

            console.log(indexS,indexE);

            if(indexE >= indexS){
                for(i = indexS+1; i< indexE ; i++){
                    if (!isSelected(seats[i])) {

                        addSeat(document.getElementById('seats'), seats[i].value);
                        seats[i].classList.toggle('selected');
                    } else {

                        removeSeat(document.getElementById('seats'), seats[i].value);
                        seats[i].classList.toggle('selected');
                    }
                }
            }
            start = end =  -1; 
        }

        if (this.classList.toggle('selected')) {
            addSeat(document.getElementById('seats'), this.value);
        } else {
            removeSeat(document.getElementById('seats'), this.value);
        }

    } else {
        alert("This seat is reserved!\nPlease select another seat");
        removeSeat(document.getElementById('seats'), this.value);
        return;
    }
}
```

my fiddle [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7J8vj/51/)

hope this will help :)

Comment: The multiple selection works only from right to left... don't think the left to right selection it's so useful.